# Paytm_iOS_All_in_One_SDK not working in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, paytm

I have integrated **Paytm_iOS_All_in_One_SDK** in my project, My app is running in devices but fail in the simulator due to this SDK. It's always shows

> Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'AppInvokeSDK.framework' was built for iOS.

Below is the link for download the Paytm SDK.

https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_iOS_All_in_One_SDK

I am using Xcode 11.4.1

Comment: can you add your code here?

Comment: I have added the Paytm framework in one folder which is resources and then I switched the Paytm framework in Framework folder. Now, it's working in both simulator and devices.@VipinSaini